# Dagger 2 - ViewPagerAdapter

Tags: android, dagger-2

I'm unsure how to go about injecting a `ViewPagerAdapter` using Dagger 2. Perhaps I don't need to use this method.

I have an `Activity` which contains a `ViewPager` and I want one of these `Fragment`s in the `ViewPager` to have access to the adapter so it can dynamically change the `ViewPager` count.

The main issue I have is I get the following error when using `@Inject` and providing the `VerticalViewPagerAdapter`:

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Handler android.support.v4.app.FragmentHostCallback.getHandler()' on a null object reference` which is thrown after attempting `super(fm)` in

```
public VerticalViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm)
    {
        super(fm);
        userProgress = 1;
    }
```

When not `@Provide`ing and instantiating with `new`, I don't get this error. I believe it has something to do with the `getSupportFragmentManager()` method.

**My MainModule:**

```
@Module
public class MainModule
{
    private final MyApplication app;

    public MainModule(MyApplicationapplication)
    {
        app = application;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    protected Application provideApplication()
    {
        return app;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    protected Resources provideResources()
    {
        return app.getResources();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    protected MainActivity provideMainActivity()
    {
        return new MainActivity();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    protected MainPresenter provideMainPresenter(MainActivity mainActivity)
    {
        return new MainPresenterImpl(mainActivity);
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    protected VerticalViewPagerAdapter provideVerticalViewPagerAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity)
    {
        // This line here
        return new VerticalViewPagerAdapter(mainActivity.getSupportFragmentManager());
    }
}
```

Comment: You should never do anything like `return new MainActivity()` in Android. Android manages the construction of your Activity, you can't construct one arbitrarily and if you do, you will end up with errors like you are getting above since merely calling the constructor does not provide a fully-functional activity. Instead, you need to use the callbacks `onCreate()` and inject there. There are many sample Dagger-2 projects that follow this pattern. See [the Google Android Architecture blueprint that uses Dagger-2](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture)

Answer (score 2):

I guess it has to do with the MainActivity that's injected in the following method in your Module:

```
provideVerticalViewPagerAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity)
```

May I suggest initializing your module with a Context that is an instance of the `MainActivity` to make sure that the Context and thus the FragmentManager are available, something like this:

```
@Module
public class MainActivityModule {
    private final MainActivity myActivity;

    public MainActivityModule(MainActivity activity) {
        this.myActivity= activity;
    }

    @Provides
    @PerActivity
    protected VerticalViewPagerAdapter provideVerticalViewPagerAdapter() {
        return new VerticalViewPagerAdapter(myActivity.getSupportFragmentManager());
    }
}
```

Then when you inject, you would have to initialize the module with the instance of the Activity like this:

```
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     DaggerMainActivityComponent
         .builder() 
         .mainComponent(MyApplication.component())
         .mainActivityModule(new MainActivityModule(this))
         .build()
         .inject(this);
 }
```

Comment: How would I then go about initialising the module? I'm only using one module at the moment and it's initialised in a `MyApplication` class with no reference to `MainActivity`. I then use `MyApplication.component().inject(this);` in the `MainActivity`

Comment: I guess you can try initializing it in the MainActivity, then inject it